# Trying to use authenticated remote signing with CFSSL (multirootca)

Tags: openssl, ssl-certificate

I'm trying to get authenticated remote signing using CFSSL by running multirootca as the CA signing server and token authentication with the CFSSL client.

On the CA server, my CA signing config (ca-signing-config.json) is:

```
{
"auth_keys": {
    "pri-auth": {
        "type": "standard",
        "key": "0123456789ABCDEF0123456789ABCDEF"
    }
},
"signing": {
    "default": {
        "usages": [
            "digital signature"
        ],
        "expiry": "52608h"
    },
    "profiles": {
        "primary": {
            "auth_key": "pri-auth",
            "usages": [
                "signing",
                "digital signature",
                "key encipherment",
                "server auth",
                "client auth"
            ],
            "expiry": "52608h"
        }
    }
}
}
```

My multirootca.conf is:

```
[primary]
private = file://primary-key.pem
certificate = primary-cert.pem
config = ca-signing-config.json
```

I'm starting multirootca using:

```
multirootca -a "127.0.0.1:8888" -l primary -roots multirootca.conf
```

Then from the client (running on the same machine in my testing):

client-config.json:

```
{           
"auth_keys" : {
   "pri-auth" : {
      "type" : "standard",
      "key" : "0123456789ABCDEF0123456789ABCDEF"
   }
},
"signing" : {
   "default" : {
      "auth_remote" : {
         "remote" : "pri-server",
         "auth_key" : "pri-auth"
      }
   }
},
"remotes" : {
   "pri-server" : "localhost:8888"
}
}
```

client.csr:

```
{
"CN": "my.test",
"Hosts": [
    "my.test"
],
"key": {
    "algo": "ecdsa",
    "size": 384
},
"names": [
    {
        "C": "US",
        "S": "Hawaii",
        "O": "Test, Inc.",
        "OU": "Test Group"
    }
]
}
```

cfssl sign command:

```
cfssl sign -config client-config.json -csr client.csr | cfssljson -bare client-output
```

The issue is that the server says the client is sending an unauthenticated requested (although it's at the correct endpoint /authsign).

Server output:

```
2019/06/21 07:22:45 [ERROR] [HTTP 401] 1 - authorisation required (received unauthenticated request)
POST /api/v1/cfssl/authsign HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:8888
Connection: close
Accept-Encoding: gzip
Connection: close
Content-Length: 1196
Content-Type: application/json
User-Agent: Go-http-client/1.1
```

Client output:

```
[ERROR] http error with http://localhost:8888/api/v1/cfssl/authsign
{"code":7400,"message":"{\"success\":false,\"result\":null,\"errors\":[{\"code\":1,\"message\":\"authorisation required\"}],\"messages\":[]}\n"}
Failed to parse input: unexpected end of JSON input
```

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're pretty close.  Once your multirootca is up and running, you should be able to use `cfssl gencert` to generate a private key and sign using the CA:

```
cfssl gencert -config=client-config.json -hostname=my.test -profile=primary client.csr | cfssljson -bare my.test
```